# [ROS2 Foxy] Topics sometimes subscribed to and sometimes published to

Tags: ros, ros2, topic, rqt, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have two Nodes who communicate with a Float32 message topic.

The typical sequence of events are:

1. Node A starts
2. Node B starts
3. Node A waits to subscribe to topic T
4. Node B creates topic T publisher
5. Node A successfully subscribes to topic T
6. Node B sends messages continually on topic T
7. Node A receives messages on topic T and runs a callback function

But sometimes (maybe 50% of times) everything happens except step 7.
Node A says it is subscribed to topic T, Node B says it is publishing on topic T, but the callback is not executed.

Debugging with `ros2 topic info /topicT -v` says that topic T has 1 subscribers but 0 publishers YET I can see values of `/topicT` in rqt using the plot plugin. So data IS being published but some subscribers can sometimes not receive the data.

Is this a known error?

My ROS application and all terminals used to run ros2 and rqt use a ROS_DOMAIN_ID and this error only happens some of the time. Mind you, Node A and Node B does a whole lot of other stuff in between each step described above.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/407495/%5Bros2-foxy%5D-topics-sometimes-subscribed-to-and-sometimes-published-to/) by [Fubbis](https://answers.ros.org/users/120002/fubbis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-10-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-10-11**:
Can you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_reproducible_example)? It will help us better understand the problem and provide you with more reasonable support.

**Comment by [Fubbis](https://answers.ros.org/users/120002/fubbis/) on 2022-10-18**:
@ravijoshi Sorry but I don't think I can do that. I have found the cause of this problem. It seems to work fine if I remove some of the publishers in Node B. It had two imageTransport camera, two imageTransport, and three other publishers, totalling in 17 topics. Is this too much for a single ROS node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am quoting the comment received above.

> It had two imageTransport camera, two imageTransport, and three other publishers, totalling in 17 topics.

This is an interesting bug with ROS Foxy. Please see a detailed report in the following link:
https://github.com/ros2/ros2/issues/1301

If possible, please upgrade your ROS distribution. For example, this issue does not occur in ROS Galactic. Or else just reduce the number of ROS publishers.

---

Originally posted by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) with karma: 1744 on 2022-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Fubbis](https://answers.ros.org/users/120002/fubbis/) on 2022-10-18**:
Insanely helpful answer. Thanks a lot!